# Notifications tracking when using FCM

Tags: android, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

Is it possible to track the notification status, whether it was opened or canceled by the user, when I send a push notification without using firebase services dashboard?

I am using `Advanced REST client` and I would like to record data about the notifications status when sending payload to `https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Conversion tracking is only built into Firebase Notifications. I don't think we have a public API to feed into those charts.

But if you send your messages through Firebase Cloud Messaging, you could:

1. record the conversion events in your app by calling [Firebase Analytics](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/android/events) explicitly
2. record more details about the converting user in your [Firebase Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start/)

You could easily accomplish the same type of functionality that way.