# How to track FCM push notifications send form server side or Rest Client?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

Is it possible to track push notification from **firebase console** which is send from server-side or Rest client.

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39386727/how-to-check-statistics-for-messages-sent-to-topics-via-fcm?rq=1 , Q: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38328341/notifications-tracking-when-using-fcm?rq=1

Comment: You can pass an ID with your notification and make sure your application receiving notification it send the information back to you, that way you will know if it arrived to its destination device.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See duplicate post.

<s>No. Currently, only messages sent through the Firebase Notifications Console are visible in the console. Messages sent through the API could be tracked in the [Diagnostics Tool](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2663268?hl=en), keeping in mind that [this doesn't include messages sent to topics](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39389049/4625829).</s>