# How to read FCM notification statistic in web app

Tags: firebase, web-applications, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

I have created notification web app that can send GCM notification to android devices, now I want to track and show the statistic of sent notification like one display in firebase notification window [Firebase Notification Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Egyau.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to track FCM push notifications send form server side or Rest Client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44697015/how-to-track-fcm-push-notifications-send-form-server-side-or-rest-client)

Comment: @AL. I wasn't sure if this is a dupe, since it seems more about reading the graphs from the notifications console.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Hi Puf. :) I see. I thought the OP was referring to the graph as a referrence to what he wanted to show based on the statistics from the messages sent through REST. It's similar that way si I figured I'd dup it.

Answer (score 1):

*firebaser here*

There is no public API for accessing the statistics from the Notifications panel in the Firebase console.

Comment: That is bad so cannot use Firebase in production :(

Comment: You could do something similar to what Firebase does under the hood: write an analytics event when the user sees/clicks the notification.

Comment: Thanks Frank, I was thinking same way.